# Is there mongodb C# driver support System.Dynamic.DynamicObject in .NET 4?

Tags: c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, dynamicobject

Im working on a project that use .NET Razor and mongodb. I would like to do something like this:

```
@{
    var feeds = DP.Database.GetCollection("feeds").FindAll();
}
<ul>
    @foreach (dynamic feed in feeds)
    {
        <li>@feed.message - @feed.from.name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

However, the current mongodb C# driver FindAll() return collection of BsonDocument which does not support dynamic object. Anybody know a .NET 4 dynamic supported mongodb C# driver?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for dynamic in the MongoDB driver.  This is because it is based on .NET 3.5.  However, since a .NET 4.0 assembly can reference a .NET 3.5 assembly, it is possible for you to write a IBsonSerializationProvider and an IBsonSerializer in .NET 4.0 to support dynamics.

We, 10gen, are looking at doing this in the future.  I have spiked some support at https://github.com/craiggwilson/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/dynamic if you want to take a look.  There are most definitely bugs, but it shows that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks Craig, i found a way to make it work. check here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/AEIfBP9IWQw

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I will echo here for SO users.  That works fine, but requires a low level modification to the core.  The way I presented above is a side-load and accomplishes the same thing without modifying the core.  Obviously, there are some differences, but it gets most of the way there.  It is just a spike after all, so...

Comment: Take a look at [MongoDB.Dynamic](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/mongodb-dynamic/wiki). It uses MongoDB official driver and take an approach of using interfaces with dynamics of C# 4.0.

Comment: Is this an official part of the driver now?

Comment: It will be in version 2.0, due out this year.

Comment: The link to https://github.com/craiggwilson/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/dynamic is no longer valid

Comment: @CraigWilson Would be good to have an update on this if possible please: the links are dead, it's 2015 and I can't find anything in the Mongo docs :)

Comment: We are still working on documentation, but we support dynamic in the 2.0.0 driver (currently in rc0): http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/what_is_new/#new-api

Answer (score 18):

I created a straight-forward extension to the MongoDB driver that re-serializes the BSON document using Json.NET and deserializes it as a dynamic. By including the following class, you can simply convert your MongoDB queries to dynamic like this

```
dynamic obj = collection.FindOneByIdAs<BsonDocument>(someObjectId).ToDynamic();
```

Extension class:

```
public static class MongoDynamic
{
    private static System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex objectIdReplace = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"ObjectId\((.[a-f0-9]{24}.)\)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
    /// <summary>
    /// deserializes this bson doc to a .net dynamic object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bson">bson doc to convert to dynamic</param>
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this BsonDocument bson)
    {
        var json = objectIdReplace.Replace(bson.ToJson(), (s) => s.Groups[1].Value);
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    }
}
```

Be sure to reference Newtonsoft.Json.dll (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: Using `bson.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings {OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict})` removes the need for all the Regex processing to remove Mongo specific Json methods.

Answer (score 5):

I have a clean solution using custom IBsonSerializer and Newtonsoft.Json.

Setup your custom serializer on the BsonClassMap

```
map.MapProperty(member => member.Data)
   .SetElementName("Data")
   .SetSerializer(new DynamicSerializer());
```

or on the property

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(DynamicSerializer))]
public dynamic Data { get; set; }
```

And just include the following class

```
public class DynamicSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
  #region Implementation of IBsonSerializer

  public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  {
    return Deserialize(bsonReader, nominalType, null, options);
  }

  public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType,
    IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  {
    if (bsonReader.GetCurrentBsonType() != BsonType.Document) throw new Exception("Not document");
    var bsonDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(bsonReader, typeof(BsonDocument), options) as BsonDocument;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(bsonDocument.ToJson());
  }

  public IBsonSerializationOptions GetDefaultSerializationOptions()
  {
    return new DocumentSerializationOptions();
  }

  public void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  {
    var json = (value == null) ? "{}": JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
    BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, typeof(BsonDocument), document,options); 
  }

  #endregion
}
```

InfoSlips - GlobalKinetic

Comment: can u give example on how to deserilze a single bsondocument into dynamic?

Answer (score 4):

Just to build on Maximilian's answer. This will return a list of dynamics from any query.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// deserializes this BsonDocument cursor result to a list of .net dynamic objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cursor">cursor result to convert to dynamic</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamicList(this MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor)
    {
        var dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();
        var list = cursor.ToList();
        for (int i = 0, l = list.Count; i < l; i++)
            dynamicList.Add(list[i].ToDynamic());

        return dynamicList;
    }
```

Comment: This seems redundant. You could just do `cursor.Select(doc => doc.ToDynamic())`. Add `.ToList()` if needed. In general, writing methods for which the framework already provides a good solution should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old topic its still just as relevant today as when post was made, and I have yet to see any solutions out there that provides a simple solution for two way support, I have modified @Maximilian Scherer code so that it lets you convert to dynamic objects which easily let you save your Document again.

```
public static class MongoDynamic
{
    /// <summary>
    /// deserializes this bson doc to a .net dynamic object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bson">bson doc to convert to dynamic</param>
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this BsonDocument bson)
    {
        var json = bson.ToJson(new MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict });
        dynamic e =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
        BsonValue id;
        if (bson.TryGetValue("_id", out id))
        {
            // Lets set _id again so that its possible to save document.
            e._id = new ObjectId(id.ToString());
        }
        return e;
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
// Get BsonDocument from db here
BsonDocument doc = ...

// Convert to dynamic.
var d = doc.ToDynamic();

// Lets add a none existant property.
d.Name = "test";

// Assuming you already have your collection set up
collection.Save(new BsonDocument(d));
```