# Query mongodb collection as dynamic

Tags: c#, mongodb, dynamic

I'm saving a `dynamic` object in my database but I would also like to retrieve it as a dynamic object. How can this be done? I tried it like so:

```
public dynamic GetItemById(ObjectId id)
{
    dynamic result = Db.GetCollection<dynamic>("Items").Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
    return result;
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

> CS1963    An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

I know this can be fixed by using a typed object instead of a dynamic one. But I don't want to use any typed objects, because that kind of defeats the entire purpose of using a NoSQL database like MongoDB (or at least, imho).

How can I query my collections by `Id` or any other property for that matter using `dynamic` objects?

Comment: What version of C# driver do you use? AFAIK, C# driver < 2.0 does not support `dynamic`, but take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21715037/4544845), maybe it is what you're looking for - especially the last comment that mentions  `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: @felix-b I'm using 2.0. That's why I was also able to save a `dynamic` object in the first place :) Tried to do it with an `ExpandoObject`, but you can't seem to do a `Filter` query with that either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the string-based syntax, since the expression doesn't offer any advantages with `dynamic` anyway:

```
var cursor = db.GetCollection<dynamic>("foo").
                Find(Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Eq("_id", someId));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fdor me! But, I do had to change `dynamic` to `ExpandoObject` to make it work.

Comment: the _id from the returned objects is not an ObjectId. Any extra steps needed for this?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis I have the same issue, dis you find a solution?

Comment: @Vivendi You can say : `var expandoObject= cursor as ExpandoObject ; `