# How to store dynamic content in MongoDB wihout using BsonDocument?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dynamic, bson

I am trying to store / read dynamic content in MongoDB. I found a built in document type called `BsonDocument` to use it for such a purpose.

However, I don't want to return from my repository `BsonDocument` type since it has some dependecies to MongoDB libraries.

What's the best alternative for this requirements? Should I use a `Dictionary<string, object>` or my own record type?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421818/query-mongodb-collection-as-dynamic) help?

Comment: @Veeram This helps but Find returns IFindFluent<TDocument, TDocument> which is not IQueryable. I would like to return IQueryable to the business layer, not any MongoDB type

Comment: You can use `var cursor = database.GetCollection<dynamic>("foo").AsQueryable();`